# App crashing, help needed understanding the error

Tags: iphone, exception

After changing "something, i can't trace back", my app is crashing with the following error:

```
2011-10-29 15:31:50.842 UnblockMe[6900:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 
'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIApplication 0x6e551b0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: 
this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key goBackButton.'
```

Only 1 class references the "goBackButton". I rebuilt the relationships to and from this button since (Yet the problem persists)

Other then this, project contains no errors or warnings. "Clean" did not seem to help. Removing app and reinstalling it on the simulator produced no results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The strange thing about that error is it's supposed to tell you what the affected object is. See [this link](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/47036-setvalue-forundefinedkey-class-not-key-value-coding-compliant-key.html) where somebody has a similar problem. What that makes me think is you have an overreleased object. That results in a pointer to nonsense memory. When you try to send a selector to it, strange things can happen.

Comment: Very insightful! I started the project as ARC, but then changed target to iOS 4.3, w/o reference counting. This definitely caused issues

Answer (score 0):

The error means that something is not properly connected in IB!

Check your xib connections, you could have renamed an outlet and you forgot to change the connections!

Comment: No indication as to what class right?

Comment: Unfortunately not, but try to check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-key. The "key about" in the error lets me think about an "about" code bad placed in a class,though

Comment: seems like you fixed the bug in the github code. But you introduced another one. The line in `AppDelegate.m` should read `self.viewController = [[MainMenu alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainMenu" bundle:nil];`

Comment: @fluchtpunkt - 10/10 man. Thank you! Please post as answer so i can accept